# iOS: Cells are not registering with TableView

Tags: ios

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13#) and stuck with Getting Started part itself. In this article cells are being registering programatically. I followed all the steps, downloaded the code and compared it mine but can't figure out the problem
**SHCAppDelegate.m**

@implementation SHCAppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[SHCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SHCViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**SHCViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        _toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_toDoItems addObject:[SHCToDoItem toDoItemWithText:@"Feed the cat"]];
        [_toDoItems addObject:[SHCToDoItem toDoItemWithText:@"Buy eggs"]];
        [_toDoItems addObject:[SHCToDoItem toDoItemWithText:@"Pack bags for WWDC"]];

      }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _toDoItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *ident = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident forIndexPath:indexPath];
    int index = [indexPath row];
    SHCToDoItem *item = _toDoItems[index];
    NSLog(@"%@",item.text);
    cell.textLabel.text = item.text;

    return cell;
}
```

Here NSLog inside `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are not getting print on console.

Answer (score 0):

after setting datasource call the reload table method as
`[self.tableview reloadData];`

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got the issue. It is with viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated. When I just used -(id) viewDidLoad, it worked fine. But I don't know why?

Comment: @Navjot This is the right way to call that method,note this is amethod in default viewcontroller delegate mechanism -http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad